# Missing navigation folder for frameworks, in Xcode 6 beta

Tags: xcode, ios7, swift, xcode6

Missing navigation folder for frameworks, in Xcode 6 beta?
I updated Xcode 6 to the latest version.
Now the frameworks folder seems to be missing from the navigation area of the IDE.
How do I get it back?
Now when I import frameworks they appear at the top of the navigation area.
Shouldn't they be imported into a targeted folder?